# When determining initiative bonus for PCs, is it dex + 1/2 level or dex mod + 1/2 level?

Tags: dnd-4e

Title says it all, my group has been using our ability score instead of ability mod and I've noticed that none of the creatures in the Monster Manual get such a high initiative bonus so early.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**It's your dexterity *modifier*.**

From the RC, p80 (*emphasis mine*):

> **Initiative Modifier:** The character's initiative modifier includes the following numbers:
>
> - One-half the character's level
> - The character's Dexterity *modifier*
> - Racial or feat bonuses
> - Any other bonuses or penalties

---

There are very few things in 4e that use your actual ability score instead of the modifier. These include:

- Consitution is added to your HP
- Feats can list a specific ability score as a requirement
- Strength determines how much you can carry